# batch script to find a particular folder in a drive

Tags: batch-file, scripting

am a newbie to the batch script, i have many folders called LIB in my drive
say it can be as LIB_data,lib,lib_ac anything that starts with lib or LIB... i want to list all these directories and sort them in which they have created in the pc and copy the latest directory contents to BATCH_LATEST_LIB_FILES folder,that will be a new folder created by this batch file.i want this new folder to be created in the path where this batch file is present. please help me with a batch script.

Comment: I think you need to at least provide an attempt, to show that you're not just fishing for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at FOR, DATE, TIME, SORT, IF, GOTO and XCOPY.

[This site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php) is a great resource for batch files.